# Why do the bullet and bell characters sometimes do not cause a beep sound when they are sent to stdout?

Tags: windows, ascii, stdout

I found out that when you send the bullet and bell characters to stdout the speakers emit a beep sound. I tried it on a computer running x86-64 Windows. It worked. Then I tried it on another computer with the same specs at the first and no beep. I think it must be a hardware issue because both computers had the same software running on them. I have not experimented with additional computers or OSs. I did observe, when testing it on the second computer, that there was a delay when the the bell or bullet characters were sent to stdout. So the only missing feature is the sound itself.
What is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Turn the volume dial to eleven.

Comment: Do other sounds work on the second machine?  When you say "the same spec" and "the same software" do you mean the exact same hardware and the exact same device driver versions?

Comment: @Hans Passant, Yes I did try adjusting the volume.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, The only similarities between the two machines is their OSs and their processors architectures. Everything else is different.

Comment: In that case, there's no reason to think it's necessarily a hardware fault.  It could just as easily be a design limitation or a problem with the device drivers.  There's no way to tell, unless you happen to have another identical machine to try it on.

Comment: Did you check that the sounds are not disabled in Windows? In the Sound property dialog on the Sounds tab you can change the sounds used for various events.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the bell character needs to be sent to STDOUT (the Perl file handle for standard out) to hear the Beep.
For example if you run a Perl script named "test.pl" having
print "\a BEEP\r\n";
using the command
Perl test.pl
it should sound the beep.

However , if you re-direct STDOUT to a file with the command 
perl test.pl > testPerl.txt
NO sound will be heard. 
This was observed on PC/Windows 10 and Mac/OS X using a bash terminal.